# Windows form doesn't show Form_Load in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace WindowsFormsApp2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            
    
            
        }
    }
```

I am watching tutorial where Form1_Load() is included

I am watching tutorial where Form1_Load() is included, is there another way to include TextBox items by coding?

Comment: To answer your question, the second method mentioned by John Alexiou: After writing the event, it is the fastest to directly use ''+='' to bind to the original event. The first method he mentioned is also a very common one. Usually we just double-click the control directly, and then the compiler automatically generates these. Once we delete the code in the view, the design interface will report an error. If you need to delete these events, you need to delete the reference in the control's lightning icon and then delete, which is the opposite of the first method he mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

CSharp and VB.NET are a bit different on how to write event handlers. In your case, you need to tell the forms designer you want to handle the `.Load` event.

1. Find the properties window in the designer for the form, and click on the lightning bolt.

   [image: fig1]
2. Now the properties window displays all the events that the form can trigger. Find `Load` and **double-click** on the space next to it.

   [image: fig2]
3. The designer will now generate the `Form1.Load()` method you are missing

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }
   }
   ```

---

**An alternative way to do this same thing.**

1. In the form constructor type `this.Load +=`  and then press the `[Tab]` button.

   [image: fig3]
2. Visual studio will fill in the code needed to handle the event wit the option to rename the event handler

   [image: fig4]

---

**A third way of handling the `Load` event**

My preferred way is to `override` the `OnLoad()` method in the form.

1. Type `override OnLoad` inside the class, and IntelliSense is going to prompt you the method to override. Select `OnLoad` and press `[Tab]`.

   [image: fig5]
2. Now you can write the same code you would have before, but inside the `OnLoad()` method *which gets called* automatically every time the `.Load` event triggers.

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnLoad(e); 

           // Write code here
       }
   }
   ```

Yes in the 20+ years of `WinForms` programming and `VisualStudio` development *some* redundancies have developed. It is not a bad thing, as VS needs to accommodate different coding styles.

There is a 4th way, that applies to `VB.NET` and involves the `Handles` keyword which makes more logical sense IMHO than the way `C#` does things, but that is just me.

Answer (score 1):

You can "wire up" events via code.

Here's an example with the `Load()` event of the Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

}
```

This can be done with any control and event, but it's easier to do via the IDE as described by Jeroen van Langen. If you're creating dynamic controls (created at run-time) then this is the way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just missed the `.Load += ` command in the constructor. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your form designer and make sure the form control self is selected. press F4 for the properties control. Press on the lightning icon for events and search for the Load event.